# Can we connect ssh with the port

Tags: php, ssh, laravel-5

I would like to know, is there somehow we can connect the port along with the server in laravel 5.2.

I would like to upload a file to a server using laravel package SSH.

Here is my connection,

```
'connections' => [
        'runtime' => [
            'host'      => '',
            'username'  => '',
            'password'  => '',
            'port' => '',
            'key'       => '',
            'keytext'   => '',
            'keyphrase' => '',
            'agent'     => '',
            'timeout'   => 10,
        ],
    ],
```

And here goes my code to connect to the server at runtime,

```
Config::set('remote.connections.runtime.host', $domain_name.':'.$host_details['ftp_port']);
Config::set('remote.connections.runtime.username', $host_details['ftp_username']);
Config::set('remote.connections.runtime.password', $host_details['ftp_password']);
Config::set('remote.connections.runtime.port', $host_details['ftp_port']);

SSH::into('runtime')->run([
  touch test.txt
]);
```

I've tried this as well

```
'connections' => [
            'runtime' => [
                'host'      => '',
                'username'  => '',
                'password'  => '',
                'key'       => '',
                'keytext'   => '',
                'keyphrase' => '',
                'agent'     => '',
                'timeout'   => 10,
            ],
        ], 
 Config::set('remote.connections.runtime.host', $domain_name.':'.$host_details['ftp_port'].':'.$host_details['ftp_port']);
    Config::set('remote.connections.runtime.username', $host_details['ftp_username']);
    Config::set('remote.connections.runtime.password', $host_details['ftp_password']);


    SSH::into('runtime')->run([
      touch test.txt
    ]);
```

In both cases, it is showing 110 timeout error. What am I doing wrong, can we connect to different ports through SSH. I can ssh using terminal. But not with Laravel.

Comment: We can't know what the problem is since you are not mentioning what you're trying to connect to and to what port. However your variable names indicate that you're trying to connect to an FTP server and if that is the case then that would not work.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a remote location using ssh. I'm not allowed to share the domain details. $domain_name is the domain name, suppose 'example.com:2200' , then ftp_username is the ssh username and other is password.

Comment: Yes, I can ssh using terminal.

Comment: So the variables are just badly named and are not in fact indicating that you are trying to connect to an FTP server (this is why variable names are important when other people read your code).

Comment: I have one doubt, do the Ftp details be same as the ssh details for all websites?

Comment: Secure FTP comes in two flavours : SFTP which is FTP over SSH (which would work with laravel's SSH) and FTPS which is FTP over SSL, which will not work over SSH. You need to make sure you're using the right one.

Comment: @apokryfos Is there any laravel package that I can connect to both

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You can however use http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php to connect to FTPS via PHP.

Comment: @apokryfos I need both, this is only for SSL rt?

Comment: The link I shared is only for FTP over SSL. I suspect your issue is not the protocol since you said you can use SSH on a terminal. Be 100% sure that you have the correct credentials and also make sure you're using the correct key files (if any)

Comment: @apokryfos My actual issue is there is a form, to selct which is it (ssl, or ssh) and username, password, port etc. On submitting the form, one must create a file in its root directory. So I want something that satisfies both.

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing package that wraps around and handles both protocols. You should probably make your own.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank You, Please let me know if you find any